# Apply css to input field using class and not id

Tags: css

I have a bunch of fields in my CMS who look like this:

```
<input aria-required="true" name="weblinktitle" id="foo1" size="25" class="myclass required form-control" type="text"><br />
```

I can choose to insert a custom class for each of them (myclass) but then I'm unable to change field appearance. I can modify the field only by targeting ID and is not what I want. How to do for modify all field inside div class "myclass" ?

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L2nht9kn/2/

What I miss ? Any clue ?

Comment: "but the solution above work well on JSfiddle but not on my side." - so you make st. bad probably. Add a link to page where it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Firebug's [css inspector](https://getfirebug.com/css) may help you understand why that's the case.

Comment: be more specific when you are adding styles so that they are not overwritten `.parentClass input`

Comment: sorry I made a mess. In fact the custom class is not applied to field itself but to a div. Here an updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/L2nht9kn/2/

Answer (score 0):

I visit that samples. second one is great.
you easily can call you input by class like this : `input.myclass` what is your problem whit this code?

```
input[type=text].myclass{
    /****your codes****/
background:red; 
}
```

Comment: sorry I made a mess. In fact the custom class is not applied to field itself but to a div. Here an updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/L2nht9kn/2/

Comment: which input you want to get style? if you want to set style for all of inputs you should write first code `input{background:red;}` but if you want certain input you should call it by ID or Class.

Comment: Or you can your custom class to input by `Jquery.addclass()`

Comment: yes I want modify all input field that are inside the DIV which have the class "myclass". The use of Jquery is not adapted.